# Windows 8 ContentProperty does not work

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I have a ContentProperty set on one of my class but when i coded in XAML it produces a XAMLParseException. Was wondering if anyone can advice me on what i can do.

Code Behind:

```
[ContentProperty(Name="Converters")]
class ChainedValueConverter: DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConvertersProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Converters", typeof(ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>), typeof(ChainedValueConverter), null);

    public ChainedValueConverter()
    {
        SetValue(ConvertersProperty, new ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IValueConverter> Converters
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>)GetValue(ConvertersProperty);
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        object _cValue = value;
        foreach (IValueConverter converter in Converters)
        {
            _cValue = converter.Convert(_cValue, targetType, parameter, language);
            if (_cValue == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                break;
        }
        return _cValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        object _cValue = value;
        foreach (IValueConverter converter in Converters)
        {
            _cValue = converter.ConvertBack(_cValue, targetType, parameter, language);
            if (_cValue == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                break;
        }
        return _cValue;
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Converts boolean value to visibility.
/// </summary>
class BooleanToVisibilityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (Boolean)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible ? true : false;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<common:ChainedValueConverter x:Key="A">
            <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter />
    </common:ChainedValueConverter>
```

The above codes when ran produces a XamlParseException with WinRT information: E_UNKNOWN_ERROR

Comment: Would it be possible that the Convert and ConvertTo methods are called and that is the exception you saw?

Comment: Where is the BooleanToVisibilityConverter class?

Comment: @gyurisc Hi, i've not called any of the methods and definitely sure of it cause i did not use any of it for data binding yet.
And edited the above post to include BooleanToVisisbilityConverter :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like your idea of a chained converter and tried to find a solution. It seems you simply need to initialize your collection in the constructor (create a new instance). See my implementation:

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "Converters")]
public class ChainedConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public ChainedConverter()
    {
        Converters = new ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConvertersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Converters", typeof (ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>), 
        typeof (ChainedConverter), new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>)));

    public ObservableCollection<IValueConverter> Converters
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>) GetValue(ConvertersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ConvertersProperty, value); }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        foreach (var c in Converters)
            value = c.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, language);
        return value; 
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        foreach (var c in Converters)
            value = c.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, language);
        return value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow it works wonder tho' i just wonder how does that constructor affect the outcome :P
Anyway your codes does work extremely well but when i just changed the name to ChainedValueConverter it just breaks o' well but thx anyway :)

Comment: You have to change the name in the dependendy property definition as well... (the XAML parser tries to add the elements to the `Converters` property but this raises an exception because the property is `null`. This is why you have to create the list manually)

Comment: Oh because according to my code there's a property metadata so i thought it will initialize properly because i put new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>())

Comment: Hi can u help me take a look at the above code which i edited. I modified it to be similar to the one u provided but it does not work hmm.. do you know what's the cause?

Comment: try using `new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<IValueConverter>))` instead of null in `ConvertersProperty = DependencyProperty...`